# Markdown editor with support for Grammarly (or similar)

Tags: windows, markdown, editor

I'm maintaining documentation for a software project and am looking for a markdown editor that integrates with Grammarly.

Currently, I use Google docs and some DIY scripting to produce clean HTML. This has worked well, but the formatting options are not great, and the presentation could have been better. I am looking at [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/), which uses Markdown as input, but since I am a non-native English, I need Grammarly or similar. I could, of course, do some copy&paste, but it is not a very effective workflow.

There are a lot of great markdown editors out there (like [MarkText](https://github.com/marktext/marktext/), [Ghostwriter](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter) & [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/)), but none of them seems to offer any Grammarly support.

Comment: Clarification: (1) Do you specifically need to _enter_ your text in MarkDown, or is the ability to save a document in MarkDown sufficient/acceptable? (2) Is Grammarly integration _specifically_ required, or is any grammar-checking capability acceptable? (3) Constraints on budget? Programs/resources already available?

Comment: (_There is a Word addin called **Writage** that will allow Word to read and save Markdown files._)

Comment: Thanks @JeffZeitlin 1) Plan is to do writing & formatting and later editing in the same interface  2) I know Grammarly and like it. As indicated in the post I am open for alternatives but based on my limited experience Grammarly is the best option. Writage could work. I will take a look! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**StackEdit**](https://stackedit.io/), that you mention, seems to be playing nice with [**LanguageTool**](https://languagetool.org/) Grammar & Spell Checker (a capable Grammarly alternative):
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising. I will have a look at LanguageTool & try to figure out if that is an viable option.